# Create a general rule for urls in Laravel

Tags: url, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I want to redirect users back to the login page if they attempt to access certain pages on my site. I want to create a general rule so that I do not have to implement it on every page for every url separately.

For example if user try to access /profile , I want them to redirect back to login page if they are not logged in. I tried doing this using group routes by putting an if condition but that did not work. Moreover I am not an expert in laravel. This is what I tried.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/users'], function () {
     if(Auth::user()){
         Route::get('/','FacebookControllers\FacebookPagesController@listUsers');
         Route::get('{id}/profile', 'FacebookControllers\FacebookPagesController@userProfile'); 
     } 
     else {
         return redirect('/'); 
     } 
});
```

Comment: for example if user try to access /profile , I want them to redirect back to login page if they are not logged in. I tried doing this using group routes by putting an if condition but that did not work. Moreover I am not an expert in laravel.
This is what I tried. `Route::group(['prefix' => '/users'], function () {
if(Auth::user()){        Route::get('/','FacebookControllers\FacebookPagesController@listUsers');
        Route::get('{id}/profile', 'FacebookControllers\FacebookPagesController@userProfile');
}
else
{
return redirect('/');
}
});`

Comment: What about the `Auth` middleware? http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups

Comment: wao thanks man, this is what I was looking for. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: np, that's what's SO is here for ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out laravel's **Auth middleware**.

Documentation here: [laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups)

Example (taken from the docs):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```